# std atomic synchronisation and non atomic variable : not a stale data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I know that this code is correct (except the `delete` not done) :

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

std::atomic<std::string*> ptr;
int data;

void producer()
{
    std::string* p  = new std::string("Hello");
    data = 42;
    ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_release);
}

void consumer()
{
    std::string* p2;
    while (!(p2 = ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire)))
        ;
    assert(*p2 == "Hello"); // never fires
    assert(data == 42); // never fires
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(producer);
    std::thread t2(consumer);
    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

However, I wonder why in the consumer thread data can not be a *stale data*. Is it because of the `acquire` operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment to `data` [*happens-before*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Happens-before) `ptr.store` call. Accessing `data` *happens-after* that call (yes, by way of synchronization with the atomic object). Therefore, the access is guaranteed to see the value previously assigned.

Comment: Even if the assignment to `data` happens-before the store call, the thread consumer could see an invalid data because of caching. That is why I wonder if it is the `acquire` operation that perform the "invalidation" of cache

Comment: The compiler must ensure that the read of a variable observes the last value assigned by a write that *happens-before* that read. How this is achieved is an implementation detail; usually, it issues a CPU-specific instruction.

Comment: Interesting - didn't know this would affect the otherwise-unsynchronised `data` object. I'm a little behind on C++'s threading model, tending to shove in a few mutexes or atomics and hope for the best ;)

Comment: How far does this go, then? Is every assignment to everything in that function protected by the barrier provided by `ptr`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can see a release ordering by something like All writes to all memory made by the calling thread before the call to to fence function are observed by all threads as occurring before all writes to all memory made by the calling thread after the call to the fence function. And the same occurs for reads. Since the store in `ptr` is guaranteed to happen after the fence function, when the `ptr` is read as non null value in other thread, it is guaranteed that all the other values wrote before this barrier are visible

Comment: To put it simple : release => flush the cache. Acquire => invalidate the cache. Consume operations are far more complex ^^

Comment: Ah right I see this is optional on top of the usual atomic semantics, a way of ordering non-atomics around it. Nice

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Think about it this way. `std::string` constructor makes a bunch of assignments to the object's members. I assume you are not surprised that `consumer` sees a fully initialized state of `*ptr` once it acquires `ptr` pointer. This works for the same reason that `data` works.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier FWIW, reasoning about acquire-release semantics as *flush the cache* would be harmful. It may lead to misimpression that these atomic operations necessarily have runtime cost. For CPU with strong memory model like x86, most store instructions *already* have acquire-release semantics, and the `std::atomic` + `memory_order_release` is only there to prevent compile-time reordering, the machine code has no difference. If you don't want to use `std::atomic`, using normal variable with a dummy `asm("":::"memory")` suffices.

Comment: @liliscent that is true yes